Title of Cartel Kidnapping Movie?
I saw a trailer a few years ago for a movie about 2 brothers who had a sister kidnapped by a woman who was the head of a cartel. She either wanted money or for the brothers to do something for her. I can't remember who played in it, but I think the Hispanic lady was a lower level star. I also think it came out about the time 2 Guns did.

Please supply as many details as possible (was it an action movie? Was it American? Do you remember anything else about the plot?) since I'm pretty sure I know what you're after and these would really help.

You are most likely talking about the film Savages released in 2012. They aren't family. The two male leads are best friends, the kidnapped girl is their girlfriend (yes, their), and the Hispanic lady head of the cartel was Salma Hayek. (2 Guns was released in 2013). The Cartel wants to take over the friends' pot business by any means, hence the threats and kidnapping.
Trailer that matches your description:



